# Ruby Watir Form Pulldown Not Found

Tags: ruby, list, select, watir

Does anybody have any insight as to how to trigger a selection in a pulldown using `Watir`?  I can't seem to get this to find that first field.  I've tried **class** (deprecated apparently), **id**, and **name**.

```
require 'webdrivers/chromedriver'
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'

Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.path = '/Applications/RF_Utilities/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome'
url = 'https://www.finditatmpg.com/Default.aspx'

a = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, headless: false
a.goto url
#   a.select(id: 'dpdCemetery_Input').select('Beechwood')  
a.select(name: 'dpdCemetery').select('Beechwood')                       # doesn't work
puts "cemetery selected"                                  # a marker

a.text_field(id: 'txtSurname').set 'Smith'                          # this works if set first
puts "last name selected"                                 # a marker

a.text_field(id: 'txtFirstname').set 'John'
puts "first name selected"                              # a marker

a.button(id: 'btnSearch_input').click                       # submit
```

The error:

```
timed out after 5 seconds, waiting for false condition on #<Watir::Select: located: false; {:name=>"dpdCemetery", :tag_name=>"select"}> (Watir::Wait::TimeoutError)
```

Update: Here is the copied syntax of the form:

```
<div id="dpdCemetery" class="RadComboBox RadComboBox_Bootstrap" style="width:300px;white-space:normal;">
  <!-- 2021.1.119.45 --><table summary="combobox" style="border-width:0;border-collapse:collapse;width:100%">
    <tbody><tr>
      <td class="rcbInputCell rcbInputCellLeft" style="width:100%;">
        <input name="dpdCemetery" type="text" class="rcbInput radPreventDecorate" id="dpdCemetery_Input" value="Select a Cemetery" autocomplete="off">
      </td>
      <td class="rcbArrowCell rcbArrowCellRight">
        <a id="dpdCemetery_Arrow" style="overflow: hidden;display: block;position: relative;outline: none;">select</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody></table><div class="rcbSlide" style="z-index:6000;display:none;"><div id="dpdCemetery_DropDown" class="RadComboBoxDropDown RadComboBoxDropDown_Bootstrap "><div class="rcbScroll rcbWidth"></div></div></div><input id="dpdCemetery_ClientState" name="dpdCemetery_ClientState" type="hidden" autocomplete="off">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that these are not "real" HTML Select/Option element dropdowns, so you can't use the `Select` class. The tag name is a `div` not a `select`.

You'll need to use something like (update - correct locator is an id not a name):

```
a.div(id: 'dpdCemetary').click
a.li(text: /Beechwood/).click
```

Comment: OK, posted the html.  I've identified the `id` for the input object in the form.  It's not part of a list and `div` is this object's parent.  I hear what you're saying, but I can't flush it out, given it's an actual `input` of type `text`.

Comment: OK, update.  `a.div(id: 'dpdCemetery').click` drops the select list, and the focus is inside a text field.  I tried using `.set('Beechwood')` but error `element click intercepted: Element <input class="rbDecorated rbPrimary" type="submit" name="btnSearch" id="btnSearch_input" value="Search" tabindex="-1"> is not clickable at point (87, 402). Other element would receive the click: <li class="rcbItem">...</li>`

Comment: @Rich_F After Drowdown drops the select list, you should write the code to click one of the option, you should not be writing into the text field. If there is a spelling mistake in your string, this kind of select list automatically rejects your string if you are writing inside the text field.

Comment: @Rajagopalan It isn't a proper `pulldown`.  It's a `JS` generated list.  The devs didn't resort to `HTML` for some reason.

Comment: Yeah, the code I showed clicks the matching li, without typing anything. Just verified there is no click intercepted with the above code. But glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
a.text_field(name: 'dpdCemetery').set('Beechwood')
```

Seems it behaves like a `text` field.  JS provides the `dropdown` list.  I was under the impression `Watir` could handle that sort of thing.